# How to use values from another table in a SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, max, toad

```
 select max(select col0 from table0) as col0, col1, col2
 from table1
```

I hope it is clear from my "pseudo code" what I am trying to do. I basically want to add one single value from `table0` to `table1` so all rows of the first column is the same value.

But Toad cannot execute this form of code. Can you suggest a way for me to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select (select max(col0) from table0) as col0, tb1.col1, tb1.col2  from table1 tb1
```

Answer (score 2):

The aggregate functions goes *within* the subquery, not around it:

```
select 
    (select max(col0) from table0) col0, 
    col1, 
    col2
from table1
```